# Dimensions of centralizers in quantum Lie algebras associated to $\mathfrak{sl}_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra

Following ideas of Woronowicz, Lyubaschenko and Sudbery defined in [Quantum Lie algebras of type $A_n$](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9510004) the notion of a quantum Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. Let me focus on the case where $q$ is not a root of unity. From their Theorems 2.2 and 2.3, we get a subspace, let's denote it by $L$, of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_n)$ of dimension $n^2-1$, which is endowed with a bracket (the restriction of the adjoint bracket on $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_n)$) and a quantum antisymmetriser. The bracket and the antisymmetriser interact with each other in such a way that some Jacobi's identities are satisfied. In the case of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, they even prove that the enveloping algebra of $L$ is close to being the locally finite part of $U_{q}(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$.

There is also a notion of quantum Lie algebra developed by Delius (see for instance [Introduction to Quantum Lie algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9605026)), which is similar to that of Woronowicz, Lyubaschenko and Sudbery.

I have basically two questions on these quantum Lie algebras.

- I have been looking on Mathscinet and Zentralblatt for references on this topic and it seems that most papers on *Quantum Lie algebras* have been published betwwen 1993 and 2003. I have had very much trouble finding recent papers on this topic. Have I been unsucessful in my inquiry on Mathscinet and Zentralblatt because I don't know how to search or is there something else? In particular I would be very interested in recent and, if possible, easily understandable by a non-expert, developments on quantum Lie algebras of classical types.
- I am especially interested in the possible dimensions of centralizers. When $q=1$ (classical limit), the possible dimensions of $\operatorname{Ker} \operatorname{ad}_{x}$ for $x \in \mathfrak{sl}_n$ (and more generally for any simple Lie algebra) are well-known, as a consequence of the Jordan decomposition for instance. I would like to know if similar results characterizing the possible dimensions of $\operatorname{Ker} \operatorname{ad}_x$ in the quantum Lie algebra case are known? (Here $x \in L$ and $\operatorname{ad}_x$ acts on $L$ as restriction of the adjoint action on $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_n)$.)

Comment: I don't know what "dimensions of commutators" mean, but your reference to $\operatorname{Ker} \operatorname{ad}_x$, which is a centraliser, suggests you meant "dimensions of centralisers", so I edited accordingly.  I hope that was OK. \\ Also, TeX note: for correct semantics and spacing, it is better to use $\operatorname{Ker} \operatorname{ad}_x$ `\operatorname{Ker} \operatorname{ad}_x` than $\mathrm{Ker} \ ad_x$ `\mathrm{Ker} \ ad_x`.  I edited that, too.

Comment: @LSpice : indeed I meant "centraliser". Thanks for your edit.